# Can I set my W10-Client running in Virtualbox to use same timezone as its host?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I am commuting between germany and UK and like to always have accurate time on my Windows-Clock. So whenever I change location, I have a script that I run to adjust the timezone. And as quick as it is - it always bugs me (just as a matter of principle) that I have to do this on my W10-Host as well as inside the virtual machine.
Isn't it possible...

- to have the VM "inherit" that setting from its host
- to have the VM simply use the "current time" from the host
- to address this otherwise?

Comment: Are you opposed to setting up the host as an NTP server and the guest as an NTP client and having them sync that way?

Comment: It sounds a bit more pain than I expected and I would not know how to do it - but if that is the only way, I'd do it ;-)

Comment: According to [Virtualbox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idm7902), "The VirtualBox Guest Additions ensure that the guest's system time is synchronized with the host time." But in my experience they don't always sync even when you install the Guest Additions. But for starters, have you installed the Guest Additions on the guest to see if they sync that way?

Comment: Yes, the extensions are there. But pls. note that the issue is not about syncing _time_, but _timezone_.

Comment: Setup the VM to use the host as it's NTP source

Answer (score 0):

*Simplest solution*:
Inside the guest vm, you can run this command:

```
net time \\<hostMachineName> /set
```

Fill in the NetBios name of your host machine, this will set the guest vm's clock to match that of your host machine, via RPC

*Even better*, you can use the windows time Service, w32time.  You can interact with this service via w32tm.exe, and it communicates UDP over port 123 (I might actually remember that one:) so have that UDP on port 123 open in your firewalls.

To set it up on the guest vm:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm.exe /unregister
w32tm.exe /config /manualpeerlist:<hostMachineName> /syncfromflags:manual
w32tm.exe /config /update
w32tm.exe /resync
w32tm.exe /register
net start w32time
```

And you can run the /resync as needed, via Task Scheduler or whatever; But I don't think that'll even be necessary, if you've registered it as a service with those parameters

*From the host machine*:
You can set the time on your guest by adding in a `/computer:<target>` switch, and run the `/resync` command from your scripts running on your host, with target being the netbios computername of the guest vm.

From the host, update the guest vm:

```
w32tm.exe /computer:<guestVM> /resync
```

See also:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/w32time/2009/08/07/net-time-and-w32time/

Comment: But would that also update the _timezone_???

Comment: @MBaas No; Configure that by creating your own image and applying it to the virtual hdds partition